# Parameter requires a function, but doesn't accept one

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Full code: http://paste2.org/Fn3Y89am

```
//render class
(function(){
    function Render(){
        this.canvas = document.getElementById('game');
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

        this.ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
        this.ctx.font = '16pt Helvetica';

        this.lastFrameTime = Date.now();
    }

    Render.prototype.drawFrame = function(){
        var self = this;

        var now = Date.now();
        var dt = now - self.lastFrameTime;

        //request next animation frame, make this
        //function the callback
        requestAnimationFrame(self.drawFrame);
    }

    Game.Render = Render;
})();
```

`requestAnimationFrame` in `Render.prototype.drawFrame` requires a function to be passed to it. As you can see in my code, I am trying to pass the `drawFrame` function that is a part of the render class into the parameter. For some reason, it keeps saying that this is not a function.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'requestAnimationFrame' on 'Window': The callback provided as parameter 1 is not a function.
```

Why is this? I've looked at several other examples and I'm doing the same thing as them. Can't quite put my finger on what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is likely with how you or someone else is calling drawFrame.  If you don't call drawFrame as a property of a Render object, then the value of `this` will be wrong inside of drawFrame.  If that value of `this` is wrong, then the value of `self` will be wrong and `self.drawFrame` will not be a function.

As it turns out, even if `self.drawFrame()` was initially called correctly, it would no longer be correct when it is called by `requestAnimationFrame()` because when you pass `self.drawFrame` as an argument, all that is passed is the function reference and then when requestAnimationFrame calls it as a callback, the reference to `self` is lost and thus `this` inside of `drawFrame` will be wrong.

I don't know how you are first calling drawFrame, but if that is correct, then you can fix your problem like this:

```
Render.prototype.drawFrame = function(){
    var self = this;

    var now = Date.now();
    var dt = now - self.lastFrameTime;

    //request next animation frame, make this
    //function the callback
    requestAnimationFrame(self.drawFrame.bind(self));
}
```

or, a method that is compatible with older browsers:

```
Render.prototype.drawFrame = function(){
    var self = this;

    var now = Date.now();
    var dt = now - self.lastFrameTime;

    //request next animation frame, make this
    //function the callback
    requestAnimationFrame(function() {self.drawFrame();});
}
```

If the first call to `obj.drawFrame()` is not being made correctly (something you don't disclose), then you will also have to fix that.

---

Two things are important to remember here.

1. The `this` pointer is determined by how a function is called.  For `drawFrame()` to work it MUST be called as `obj.drawFrame()` where `obj` is a `Render` object.
2. When you pass an argument as `self.drawFrame`, the reference to `self` gets lost and `drawFrame()` is then not called correctly by `requestAnimationFrame()`.  That's why you need an intermediate function (which `.bind()` creates, but can also be done with your own anonymous function) in order to call `drawFrame()` properly.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe IE 8 and below doesn't support the bind function...so I guess I'll have to use the fallback method. Thanks for that!

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't self in your context the actual function?

`Render.prototype.drawFrame = function()` and then you immidietly call `self=this`, in this context `this` is the actual function you're currently in. you can try console.log(self) and see what you get

Comment: I tried just "self", and it still returns the same error. Good catch, though!

Comment: is `self` a proper function when you console.log it?